# Storing Image in wrong direction

Tags: android

Image taken in portrait mode will be saved in landscape. But images taken in the landscape mode are saved correctly.

```
private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {

        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        int rotate = 0;
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/SELFie");
            dir.mkdirs();
            String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());

            // Before saving to the file rotate to portrait and save it in a right ratio.

            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
            Log.d("SaveImageTask","It is a OutPut media file");
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(outFile));
            Log.d("SaveImageTask","OutStream");

            // writing data to the file

            outStream.write(data[0]);
            Log.d("SaveImageTask","writing the data to the outStream");
            outStream.flush();

            Log.d("SaveImageTask","OutStream.flush");
            outStream.close();

              Log.d("SaveImageTask","closing the outStream");
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " +       outFile.getAbsolutePath());

             // Refreshing the gallery to save recently taken photos.

             refreshGallery(outFile);

             // After calling the refreshGallery method.

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
        }
        return null;

        // Finally returning the null.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some Android camera hardware will create portrait images in landscape, with an EXIF header in the JPEG file indicating that the image viewer should rotate the image.

Some Android camera hardware will create portrait images as portrait.

There is nothing that you can really do about this. You are welcome to scan the resulting JPEG for the EXIF header and rotate the image yourself, but this is slow and memory-intensive.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I would be more thankful if u help me in rotating the image before saving to the gallery. I also need to handle the aspect ratio of the image before saving to the gallery.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on rotating http://eventuallyconsistent.net/2011/07/21/rotating-a-bitmap-in-android/